# WCF Client from windows handheld 6.5

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-mobile-6.5, handheld

I am experiencing a problem which I cannot seem to solve.

I have created a WCF service which is currently hosted in a console application for testing purposes.

I created a client using the compact framework version of svcutil.exe and created a windows handheld 6.5 application which is running on a mobile device.

However when sending attempting to call the WCF service I get the error:

There was no endpoint listening at {"URL"} that could accept the message...

I have created another client as a console application on a PC using svcutil.exe and this works fine.

Are there any reasons why the mobile device cannot connect to the service and the console client can??

I can ping the server from the mobile device.

Thanks

Comment: What `Binding` are you using? `Smart device` applications can only work with `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: Ah sorry, should have included that. I am using basicHttpBinding

Comment: However I have just noticed that Internet Explorer on the devices shows the page cannot be displayed - could not find server or DNS error when trying to do anything. Could this affect it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be some sort of DNS related issue.

While the WiFi connection was fine attempting to visit any website returned a Dns error.

Turning the device off and on again seemed to solve the problem as after powering back up both the application and internet explorer were working fine.

Has any else ever experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

To connect a `Smart-Device` application to a `WCF service` you should use the `NetCFSvcUtil.exe` tool.
You can download it from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/08/10/just-released-patch-to-make-netcfsvcutil-exe-work-on-windows-7-and-other-operating-systems.aspx).